# How can I find which version of libmysqlclient is installed in Centos?

Tags: centos, libraries, version

I have a custom exe provided to me but to install it I need an older version of libmysqlclient. How can I check which version is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Package might not be installed

When people give you information like this you need to make sure you qualify what it actually is. The name `libmysqlclient` is the name of the share library files that are part of this package, `mysql-libs`, typically.

You can use `repoquery` to look for a corresponding package(s) to start:

```
$ repoquery --whatprovides *libmysqlclient*
mysql-libs-0:5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-devel-0:5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-libs-0:5.1.71-1.el6.i686
mysql-devel-0:5.1.71-1.el6.i686
abi-compliance-checker-0:1.99.8.5-1.el6.noarch
```

If you understand how packages get named, then the `.so` files which are "libraries" are in the `-libs` packages quite often.

```
$ repoquery -l mysql-libs-0:5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 | head -9
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/mysql-x86_64.conf
/etc/my.cnf
/usr/lib64/mysql
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
/usr/share/doc/mysql-libs-5.1.71
/usr/share/doc/mysql-libs-5.1.71/COPYING
...
```

Here you can see the file you're asking about, `libmysqlclient`. So you can see this particular package would provide you with `.so.16`.

#### Package is already installed

If the files were already installed on the system and you knew that `libmysqlclient` was a file then you can look to RPM for this info:

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16
```

But this would require you to know where this file resided. So instead you can use `yum` to "search" for it:

```
$ yum whatprovides "*libmysqlclient*"
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to ask RPM which version it is: `rpm -q mysql-devel`.

You could also use `yum info mysql-devel`.

If you need the ABI version of the library itself, you need to say something like `ls /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient*`. CentOS 6 ships ABI version 16 libraries, for example. Use `lib` instead of `lib64` for a 32-bit system.