# How to find a package name and version by its library name and version using a shell command?

Tags: package-management, shared-library, oracle-linux, mariadb

Is there a command that could give me a package name and version for a library?

For example, I want to get `mariadb-libs` version for `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` library that is currently not installed, but required.

***Updated after answer reading:***

`yum whatprovides "*libmysqlclient*"` shows no `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` library listed. Only so.18 libraries are displayed for `ol7_latest` repository for different versions of mariadb-libs (`5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64,`5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64`, 5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64`).

OS: Oracle linux 7.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find which version of libmysqlclient is installed in Centos?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114004/how-can-i-find-which-version-of-libmysqlclient-is-installed-in-centos)

Comment: The question linked above is different, but the answer provides the information requested here.

Comment: I've tried those commands but it prints information about so.18 library. Maybe some repositories or repository archive should be enabled to show in which package could be so.16 library, not so.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`yum whatprovides`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html):

> **provides** or **whatprovides**
>
> Is used to find out which package provides some feature or
>   file. Just use a specific name or a file-glob-syntax wildcards
>   to list the packages available or installed that provide that
>   feature or file.

e.g:

```
yum whatprovides "*libmysqlclient*"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But it shows only something like: `1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64` and then `Provides    : libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)`. If there way to show which packages contain `libmysqlclient.so.16`? Or is it impossible for system that does not have access to repositories with `mariadb-libs` that contain `libmysqlclient.so.16` version?

Comment: It almost answers the title's question, so I think I could approve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I think, it impossible to get old version of library using only simple shell command. To find it I've used [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libmysqlclient.so.16&submit=Search%20...)
[image: rpmfind.net with library name search keword inputed]

It shows, that this library version available for `el6` system, not for `el7`. Maybe it is possible to get such information in `el7` by enabling repositories for `el6`, but it has no sense. Installation from wrong repositories could break system. And it is more easier to use rpmfind instead of using command that requires additional repositories enabling. So if the library is required it is better to install *Oracle Linux 6* for this or other version printed out on rpmfind.